# Why can't I throw an exception in a Java 8 lambda expression?

Tags: java, exception, lambda, java-8

I upgraded to Java 8 and tried to replace a simple iteration through a Map with a new lamdba expression. The loop searches for null values and throws an exception if one is found. The old Java 7 code looks like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    if(entry.getValue() == null) {
        throw new MyException("Key '" + entry.getKey() + "' not found!");
    }
}
```

And my attempt to convert this to Java 8 looks like this:

```
myMap.forEach((k,v) -> {
    if(v == null) {
        // OK
        System.out.println("Key '" + k+ "' not found!");

        // NOK! Unhandled exception type!
        throw new MyException("Key '" + k + "' not found!");
    }
});
```

Can anyone explain why the `throw` statement not allowed here and how this could be corrected?

Eclipse's quick-fix suggestion does not look right to me... it simply surrounds the `throw` statement with a `try-catch` block:

```
myMap.forEach((k,v) -> {
    if(v == null) {
        try {
            throw new MyException("Key '" + k + "' not found!");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: There's a very simple answer: lambda expressions are a concise means of implementing a functional interface.  Just like any other way to implement an interface, you have to conform to the interface contract -- which means you can only throw the exceptions allowed by the target type.  There's no magic here.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You are not allowed to throw checked exceptions because the [`accept(T t, U u)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html#accept(T,U)) method in the [`java.util.function.BiConsumer<T, U>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) interface doesn't declare any exceptions in its `throws` clause. And, as you know, [`Map#forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) takes such a type.

```
public interface Map<K, V> {

    default void forEach(BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action) { ... }

}                        |
                         |
                         V
@FunctionalInterface
public interface BiConsumer<T, U> {

    void accept(T t, U u); // <-- does throw nothing

}
```

That is true when we are talking about checked exceptions. But you still can throw an unchecked exception (e.g. a [`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)):

```
new HashMap<String, String>()
    .forEach((a, b) -> { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); });
```

Comment: I pretty much agree with this answer. The confusing thing about the javadocs is the statement "Exceptions thrown by the action are relayed to the caller.".  As a side note, throwing exceptions within a lambda is certainly allowed, just not in this particular case.

Comment: @micker It may be worth pointing out:  that statement is only attached to the `forEach` default member method of the `Iterable<T>` interface.  The primary Stream/Consumer `forEach` doesn't document anything about checked exception behavior (although some conclusions can be drawn from the function signatures).

Comment: @andrew-tobilko, thanks for your answer! I wonder if we have a similar case in java Optional.ifPresentOrElse where we can't also throw any checked exception.

Answer (score 30):

You can throw exceptions in lambdas.

A lambda is allowed to throw the same exceptions as the functional interface implemented by the lambda.

If the method of the functional interface doesn't have a throws clause, the lambda can't throw CheckedExceptions. (You still can throw RuntimeExceptions).

---

In your particular case, `Map.forEach` uses a `BiConsumer` as a parameter, BiConsumer is defined as:

```
public interface BiConsumer<T, U> {
    void accept(T t, U u);
}
```

A lambda expression for this functional interface can't throw CheckedExceptions.

---

The methods in the functional interfaces defined in `java.util.function` package don't throw exceptions, but you can use other functional interfaces or create your own to be able to throw exceptions, i.e. given this interface:

```
public interface MyFunctionalInterface<T> {
    void accept(T t) throws Exception;
}
```

The following code would be legal:

```
MyFunctionalInterface<String> f = (s)->throw new Exception("Exception thrown in lambda");
```