# Map Object Array to Int Array

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to map and filter my Object[] array to int[] array. Works great, if an object is an int, but throws cast exception if not. I'm wondering if I can somehow attach an try/catch in lambda expression? Here's my code:

```
b[i] = Arrays.stream(item).mapToInt(e -> (int) e).filter(e -> e % 2 != 0).toArray();
```

or better way is just to try/catch whole block?

Comment: What is expected behaviour, when some objects are ints and other are not?

Comment: Yeah, of course. Im just wondering how to try/catch that without dropping whole array.

Comment: either use a `filter` so that you only map valid objects, or move `e -> (int) e` into its own method, where you place that `try/catch`.

Comment: Why would you use try/catch for that? Wouldn't make it so much more sense to use `filter` to get to find every array item which is a number before trying to convert it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I throw an exception in a Java 8 lambda expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726874/why-cant-i-throw-an-exception-in-a-java-8-lambda-expression)

Comment: It’s become an aside now, but you may use try/catch within your lambda; could be useful in other cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wy not filter objects that are Integers?

```
.filter(i -> i instanceof Integer).mapToInt(e -> (int) e)
```

Comment: Yeah, why didn't I think of that? Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, without use of `lambda`: `.filter(Integer.class::isInstance) .mapToInt(Integer.class::cast)`

Answer (score 3):

Use `filter()` to remove non-numerical values, then convert to `Number` and call the `intValue()` method.

```
int[] ints = Arrays.stream(objects)
    .filter(Number.class::isInstance)
    .map(Number.class::cast)
    .mapToInt(Number::intValue)
    .toArray();
```

Comment: Testing with `instanceof Number`, followed by casting to `int` is obviously broken. Either, test for `instanceof Integer` or use `.mapToInt(o -> ((Number)o).intValue())`. Using `.map(o -> (Number) o) .mapToInt(Number::intValue)` instead of a single `mapToInt` creates the impression of an irrational affinity to method references.