# Java 8: Checked exception in forEach clause

Tags: java-8

Got a `List<String>` iterated as follow:

```
void validateValue() throws ValidationException { 
    aList.forEach(k -> validateValue(k));
}

void validateValue (String s) throws ValidationException {
    ..
}
```

But the compiler says:
`Unhandled exception type ValidationException`

Seems the exception has to be handled in the `forEach` clause.

Is that normal or is there a turn around (beside Java 7 style iteration below that pass)?

```
void validateValue() throws ValidationException {
    for(String k : aList) {
        validateValue(k);
    }
}
```

Comment: please, look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37726990/4922375

Comment: Thanks guys. Will also mark my question as duplicate